# The $8$-Puzzle and $2$-Cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, puzzle

I have been studying the $8$-puzzle and have thus far managed to wrap my head around the following information:

The following illustrates the *solved* position of the $8$-puzzle, where $9$ is the empty tile:

$$
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\ 
4 & 5 & 6\\ 
7 & 8 & 9
\end{matrix}
$$

Suppose that I have the following *valid* position of the $8$-puzzle:

$$
\begin{matrix}
a & b & c\\ 
d & e & f\\ 
g & h & i
\end{matrix}
$$

If I enumerate its tiles, beginning at $1$, from left to right and from top to bottom, then applying the following permutation to it solves it:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\ 
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Is decomposing this permutation into a sequence of *valid* $2$-cycles what I now have left to do? I deem a $2$-cycle $(p\;q)$ as valid if either $p$ or $q$ is the empty tile, and if the other tile is either vertically or horizontally adjacent to this empty tile.

Have I understood and laid this problem correctly? Thanks in advance.